Django project structure: should my register, login templates go into an accounts app or in project templates
This is the project structure I have currently:
project/
  manage.py
  forum_app/
  ecommerce_app/. # tbd
  accounts/
  project/
    settings.py
    urls.py
  templates/
    base.html
    home.html
    registration/
      login.html
      signup.html
      profile.html
      change_password.html
      ...

Should I instead have something like this:
project/
  manage.py
  forum_app/
  ecommerce_app/ # tbd
  accounts/
    templates/
      accounts/
        login.html
        signup.html
        profile.html 
        change_password.html
  project/
    settings.py
    urls.py
  templates/
    base.html
    home.html

My confusion comes with the idea that since authentication is a specific set of tasks it should be a seperate app, so the relevant templates should go in the accounts app.
However, the login, signup etc. templates are intended for the website as a whole, so maybe they should go in the root templates folder as in first example.
I'd appreciate some guidance on what is the best way to do this?
Also, if I were to create a Profile model for forum users (profile icon, bio) mapping to auth User, should that live in the accounts/models.py or forum_app/models.py?

Which apps use which templates? Organize them together and use template namespacing.

In Django you can place templates either inside apps or in the root directory, it depends on your project. if you place templates inside apps, you can reuse that app in other projects and it will be easier to manage for large projects.
If you are placing templates in the root directory, don't forget to mention the path of templates in settings.py
I hope this has been helpful for you.

Yeah, I decided to put everything into the accounts app in the end. I personally found it tidier, and urls work just fine regardless of where I put them.
